# Jquery : Increase column width with mouse events

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to increase/decrease width of table columns with MOUSE events by using JQuery. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#drag').on('mousedown', function(e){
    var $dragable = $(this).parent(),
        startWidth = $dragable.width(),
        pX = e.pageX;

    $(document).on('mouseup', function(e){
        $(document).off('mouseup').off('mousemove');
    });
    $(document).on('mousemove', function(me){
        var mx = (me.pageX - pX);
        //var my = (me.pageY - pY);

        $dragable.css({
            left: mx / 2,
            width: startWidth - mx,
            //top: my
        });
    });

});
```

});

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wSTcJ/2/)

Hope It Helps you'

Comment: nice demo, but didn't he ask for table columns?

Comment: thats nice demo. But i want to have double arrow mark on mouse over on the table line and i should be able to move right or left which automatically has to increase/decrese the width of the table column.